# Is it possible to Customize FaceBook PostView in iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm using social framework to share with FaceBook. Is it possible to change the text on indicated buttons in the following screenshot?
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Not yet, All you can do is overlap their buttons etc with your custom button text etc, and when it is tapped then pass on touches/events to the background button.

Comment: Thanks. And can you please suggest how can we access this postview?

Comment: Which postview, the one you have displayed above in the screenshot? These are native dialogs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.5/class/FBNativeDialogs Also you can play around with Dialogs and WebDialogs if needed - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.5/

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much for your information Mr. Reno :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes You can do it with bellow Method integration if you can send message using social framework to share with FaceBook.

you just need to add this :-

```
- (void)findSubViewofFB:(UIView*)theView
{
    for (UIView * subview in theView.subviews)
    {
      //  subview.hidden=TRUE;

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)subview;

            if([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Send"])
            {
                [btn setTitle:@"msg" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }
        }
        [self findSubViewofFB:subview];
    }
}
```

and add this above method in your message send class:-

```
 [self findSubViewofTwitter:facebook.view];
```

i just tested it in my twitter integration of using social framework and change send Button Title as using above method and my Tweet message box look like:-

[image]

Comment: But can you please tell me where to call [self findSubViewofFB:objFB.view]?

Comment: are u using this method SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [controller setInitialText:message]; this method

Comment: Exactly.. It's working for twitter but not working for faceboook. Any solution please?

Comment: for facebook>> subviews count is 0. So any solution to get like Twitter?

Comment: i just thought that it wokring for facebook i am just impliment twiter my frnd

Comment: ohh! i'm not getting why it is behaving like that. But viewController's view should have subviews naaa?
Anyway thanks for your info dear. :)

Comment: Most likely, the Facebook compose view controller is a remote view controller, meaning its internals are in a separate sandbox and therefore unusable in the app. If this is true, the Twitter compose view controller wouldn't have become one in order to not break apps that modify its private properties, like this.